# Fill the area under a step plot in Bokeh

Tags: python, visualization, bokeh

I have a simple step graph and I would like to fill the area under the graph but Im missing something because it's not displayed correctly. This is my working code:

```
import numpy as np
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, NumeralTickFormatter, DaysTicker, DatetimeTickFormatter, HoverTool, Patch
from math import pi

from datetime import datetime

datetimes = [datetime(2022, 9, 30, 3, 8, 8, 239000, ),
             datetime(2022, 10, 1, 3, 8, 8, 239000, ),
             datetime(2022, 10, 20, 3, 8, 8, 239000,)]
             
values = np.random.random(3)

fig = figure(x_axis_type="datetime", toolbar_location=None, y_range=(0, 1), y_axis_location='right', height=250, width=635)
fig.yaxis[0].formatter = NumeralTickFormatter(format='0%')
fig.xaxis.major_label_orientation = pi/4
fig.xaxis.formatter=DatetimeTickFormatter(
        hours=["%d %B %Y"],
        days=["%d %B %Y"],
        months=["%d %B %Y"],
        years=["%d %B %Y"],
    )
hover = HoverTool(tooltips=[('values', '@values{0.0%}')])
fig.toolbar.active_drag = None
plot_source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(date=datetimes, values=values))
line_plot = fig.step("date", "values", source=plot_source, line_width=1, color="#285e61")
fig.add_tools(hover)
fig.varea(source=plot_source, x="date", y1=0, y2="values",
          alpha=0.2, fill_color='#38b2ac')

show(fig)
```

And this is the resulting plot:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is to have each timestamp for the area twice, one value for the left side of the step and on for the right.

### Miminal Example

```
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime


from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_notebook
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, NumeralTickFormatter, DaysTicker, DatetimeTickFormatter, HoverTool, Patch
output_notebook()

datetimes = np.array([
    datetime(2022, 9, 30, 3, 8, 8, 239000, ),
    datetime(2022, 10, 1, 3, 8, 8, 239000, ),
    datetime(2022, 10, 20, 3, 8, 8, 239000,)
])

values = np.random.random(3)

fig = figure(
    x_axis_type="datetime",
    toolbar_location=None,
    y_range=(0, 1),
    y_axis_location='right',
    height=250,
    width=635
)
fig.yaxis.formatter = NumeralTickFormatter(format='0%')
fig.xaxis.major_label_orientation = np.pi/4
fig.xaxis.formatter=DatetimeTickFormatter(days="%d %B %Y")
hover = HoverTool(tooltips=[('values', '@values{0.0%}')])
fig.toolbar.active_drag = None

# main change here
plot_source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(
    date=datetimes.repeat(2)[1:],
    values=values.repeat(2)[:-1]
))

line_plot = fig.step("date", "values", source=plot_source, line_width=1, color="#285e61")
fig.add_tools(hover)
fig.varea(source=plot_source, x="date", y1=0, y2="values",
          alpha=0.2, fill_color='#38b2ac')

show(fig)
```

### Output

[image: filled area below step plot]

### Comment

I use [`np.reapeat()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) to repeat all values in the `np.array`.

Answer (score 0):

This was implemented in Bokeh v3.2, see [figure.varea_step()](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/plotting/figure.html#bokeh.plotting.figure.varea_step)
and [example](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/examples/basic/areas/varea_step.html):

```py
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show

p = figure(width=400, height=400)

glyphs = p.varea_step(
    x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    y1=[12, 16, 14, 13, 15],
    y2=[1, 4, 2, 1, 3],
    step_mode='after')

show(p)
```